# Looping over folder to resize images using tensorflow image resize error

Tags: tensorflow

I'm looping over a folder with jpgs to resize them to 256x256 with the following

```
directory = 'example'
import os
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
 tf.image.resize(filename, (256,256))
```

But I get the error "'images' must have either 3 or 4 dimensions". I was able to print out the name of each file in the folder, so the loop isn't the issue.

Comment: tf.image.resize does not accept file paths, you need to load the image to pass it to this function.